# How to get udev to identify a USB device regardless of the USB port it is plugged in?

Tags: udev

I'd like to write a script that backups data on a USB device every time the latter is getting plugged in a random USB slot. Now I know about the `KERNEL=sdX` identifier but the problem is that depending on the slot and on whether other devices are already plugged in the `sdX` will change. What would be the best way to identify my USB device in udev ? I've been thinking about using `partuuid` but I don't know how and I don't know where the partuuid is stored in the first place or how it is worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you partition your device using `gdisk` as opposed to `fdisk` you will create a GPT-style partition table which, for each partition, can hold a PARTUUID and a PARTLABEL. The `c` command in `gdisk` allows you to set the partition name, ie the PARTLABEL.

These partition ids do not change when you reformat the partition by creating a new filesystem on it.

Most filesystems allow you to get or set a UUID and LABEL on the filesystem. The means to do so depends on the filesystem type, eg for ext3/4 it is `tune2fs` with `-U` and `-L`. These appear as UUID and LABEL in Linux.

Do not confuse these 2 sets of ids. `blkid` will show all of them:

```
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="MYLABEL" UUID="A369-D716" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="My new partition" \
  PARTUUID="f0817245-d3ce-408b-9457-e33dfc04aebe"
```

---

You can see the udev attributes with

```
$ udevadm info -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdb1)
...
E: ID_FS_LABEL=MYLABEL
E: ID_FS_LABEL_ENC=MYLABEL
E: ID_FS_UUID=A369-D716
E: ID_FS_UUID_ENC=A369-D716
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID=f0817245-d3ce-408b-9457-e33dfc04aebe
E: ID_PART_TABLE_UUID=7301d696-b66d-4f85-8272-7dd5e29175ae
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_NAME=My\x20new\x20partition
```

Comment: the label name is stored somewhere in the GUID table ?

Comment: The PARTLABEL is held in the GPT partition table array. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_entries)

Comment: How do I access the label attribute in udev, I can't find the label attribute

Comment: I added the attributes shown by `udevadm` to my answer.

Comment: yeah I saw that but can you actually use ATTRS{ID_FS_LABEL_ENC} I'm not sure those are attributes usable in a udev rule. Gonna try anwyay

Comment: Sorry, they are not attributes but values in the environment, so use `ENV{ID_FS_LABEL_ENC}=="..."`

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar, using the UUID (Universally Unique Identifier library) of the USB device.

You can see UUIDs with blkid command:

```
# blkid
```

You can find more information about blkid, looking into it's man page

```
# man blkid
```